# Html5 WebSql transaction behaves strangely with alert

Tags: javascript, html, transactions, local-storage, web-sql

The WebSql's transaction is behaving strangely when I put some alerts in the code. I have three transactions to do. These are t1,t2 and t3.

The following code works perfectly fine as expected.

```
 var db = openDatabase('DBTest', "1.0", "Example DB", "200000");
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        alert('Tranasction.1........');
        jQuery('body').append('<h1>Added a h1 by t1</h1>');
    });
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        alert('Tranasction.2........');
        jQuery('body').append('<h1>Added a h1 by t2</h1>');
    });
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        alert('Transaction.3.........');
        jQuery('body').append('<h1>Added a h1 by t3</h1>');
    });
```

But, when I insert an alert statement just before doing a transaction. The things do not work as expected.

For example. If I put an alert('An alert just before transaction t3');

The code after the change looks like this:

```
var db = openDatabase('DBTest', "1.0", "Example DB", "200000");
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        alert('Tranasction.1........');
        jQuery('body').append('<h1>Added a h1 by t1</h1>');
    });
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        alert('Tranasction.2........');
        jQuery('body').append('<h1>Added a h1 by t2</h1>');
    });
    //THIS ALERT IS ADDED
    alert('An alert just before transaction t3');
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        alert('Transaction.3.........');
        jQuery('body').append('<h1>Added a h1 by t3</h1>');
    });
```

**Change in behavior after the changes:
The first two transactions do not happen.**

Is it the expected behaviour. If yes, then how is it justified?

Comment: Im having similar issue. Do you know what the issue is?

Comment: I dont have exact explanation for it, but replacing alert with console.log resolves the issue..

Comment: I am having the issues with alerts also.

Comment: I had a issue with this as well. Inserts when testing with chrome would not work all the time and I removed the alert and now it seemed to work. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have here is working as expected in Chrome.  I just opened up the developer tools and pasted your code into the console and can see that all three transactions are created.

Remember that the `db.transaction` function calls are asynchronous, so they will return immediately but not necessarily call the callbacks you pass in until they've actually created the transactions.

Here's the order of execution I think is happening:

> openDatabase(...)
>
> db.transaction #1 (begins creating transaction, returns immediately)
>
> db.transaction #2 (begin...)
>
> alert displays before transaction 3
>
> db.transaction #3 (begin...)
>
> db.transaction #1 callback (alert transaction 1)
>
> db.transaction #2 callback (alert transaction 2)
>
> db.transaction #3 callback (alert transaction 3)